# Start a program from Batch while preventing duplicates

Tags: windows, batch-file, process, task

I am starting a program from Batch, but if the program is already running, I want to avoid starting a second instance.

So far, I have crafted the following code, which seems to work:

```
TASKLIST /FI "IMAGENAME eq speedfan.exe" | FIND "speedfan.exe" >NUL
IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (
    TASKKILL /F /IM speedfan.exe
)
START "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\SpeedFan\speedfan.exe"
```

Alternatively, if I want to keep the current instance instead of starting a new one:

```
TASKLIST /FI "IMAGENAME eq speedfan.exe" | FIND "speedfan.exe" >NUL
IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (
    START "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\SpeedFan\speedfan.exe"
)
```

Can this be improved/simplified?

**Update:** Thank you all for your comments! So far, my revised code is becoming:

```
TASKLIST /FI "IMAGENAME eq speedfan.exe" | FINDSTR /BLI "speedfan.exe " >NUL || (
    START "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\SpeedFan\speedfan.exe"
)
```

(and maybe I'll drop the `/FI "IMAGENAME eq speedfan.exe"` part for the sake of simplicity)

Comment: `TASKLIST /FI "IMAGENAME eq speedfan.exe" | FIND "speedfan.exe" >NUL || START "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\SpeedFan\speedfan.exe"`

Comment: As Stephan as shown, you can use conditional execution. A `&&` means execute this command if the previous command was successful. A `||` means execute this command if the previous command was not successful.

Comment: Interesting :) Yet, are there other alternatives? (I'd prefer avoiding a long one-liner). But mainly, is there an better option than my "tasklist/find" method?

Comment: You can use parentheses with conditional execution just like you did with the `IF` command. You are essentially doing this task as about as efficient as you can. If you want to slow it down, feel free to use `WMIC` or `Powershell` to see if the task is running.

Comment: You could probably shorten your initial command line length too, `TASKLIST /FI "IMAGENAME eq speedfan.exe" | FIND "speedfan.exe"` could be `TASKLIST | FIND /I "speedfan.exe "`. _This assumes that you do not have another executable whose name ends with `speedfan.exe`_

Comment: @Squashman I'm not looking for the fastest code (irrelevant here), but for the robustest and simplest ;)

Comment: @Compo These are actually very old codes of mine, guess I did this to improve robustness (reduce risk of false positives, even if it's very unlikely here).

Comment: Okay for robustness, you can shorten it but use `FindStr` instead of `Find`. For example, `TASKLIST | FINDSTR /I "\<speedfan\.exe\>"` or  `TASKLIST | FINDSTR /BLI "speedfan.exe "`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick example intended to request input confirmation to close it, if it is running, or to just open it if isn't running. I hope it is robust enough for your purposes.

```bat
@"%__AppDir__%tasklist.exe" /Fi "ImageName Eq speedfan.exe" /Fo CSV /NH^
 | "%__AppDir__%find.exe" ":" > NUL && (
    Start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\SpeedFan\speedfan.exe") || (
    "%__AppDir__%choice.exe" /M "Would you like to close SpeedFan"
    If Not ErrorLevel 2 "%__AppDir__%taskkill.exe" /Im speedfan.exe /T > NUL)
```

*I have split the long first line over two for tidiness, and because you don't particularly like long lines.*

Comment: Maybe the `%__AppDir__%` environment variables are a bit overkill 

Comment: No they aren't! you asked for robustness, without that variable, the code would be reliant upon the PC or User not having incorrectly modified, _(deliberately or accidentally)_, the content of `%PATH%`. It is my experience that many people have done exactly that!

Comment: Indeed, executable shadowing…